# suds: google app engine support

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, soap, suds

I'm trying to use suds in a python Google App Engine application. This is
the traceback:

```
client = Client(url)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/sandbox/test.349741318547153856/suds/client.py",
line 109, in __init__
    options.cache = ObjectCache(days=1)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/sandbox/test.349741318547153856/suds/cache.py",
line 141, in __init__
    location = os.path.join(tmp(), 'suds')
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/tempfile.py",
line 45, in PlaceHolder
    raise NotImplementedError("Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is
available for use")
NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use
```

I tried changing line 109 at **client.py**:

```
options.cache = ObjectCache(days=1)
```

to:

```
options.cache = None
```

And it works now but I'm not sure if that can affect something in the
future.

I really appreciate if anybody can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to local files in appengine. Thats why you get that error it's trying to write a cache of processed WSDL to a temporary file.  You will have to not cache or provide an alternate cache mechanism.  I am using suds on appengine with a very expensive WSDL file, so I hacked the caching to write the cache on the dev server filesystem and then uploaded the cache, with the deployed code.

I cheated - sort of.

```
def precache_wsdl(wsdl,principal):
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel = logging.info
    cache_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"cache")
    security = Security()
    token = UsernameToken(*principal)
    security.tokens.append(token)
    client = Client(wsdl,cache=FileCache(cache_location))
    client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

I defined this bit of code in my appengine code.  Loaded up the remote command api, ran it locally,
prepopulating the cache.  Then I amde sure that cach_location was set correctly in my real appengine code.  When you run in the remote_api shell you are not running with the same restrictions that server code is.  In fact you don't even have to run it under the shell, but I tend to do a lot that way.

Comment: Thanks buddy..for your prompt response...
Could you please explore, how did you hacked?

Comment: Ok..Buddy..one thing i wanted to confirm, if i use options.cache = None, is that impacting on performance or any other things.?

Comment: If you don't cache then you incurr the cost of retrieving and reparsing the wsdl file at least every time an instance starts.  The proper way would be to write your own Cache implementation that stores it in the datastore or blobstore (depending on size).

Answer (score 2):

Use jurko-suds from pip, and set `cache=` in your constructor.

```
from suds.cache import NoCache
[...]
client = Client(url, cache=NoCache())
```